# install cgal as non root user + error due to gmp

Tags: installation, gmp, cgal

I want to install CGAL in my account in our cluster; as a prerequisite, I installed PMG in a folder, and according to this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265239/how-to-install-a-custom-gmp-lib-for-just-one-user 
I added some lines to the content of the .bashrc file.

```
GMP_DIR="${HOME}/gmp-6.1.2"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${GMP_DIR}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=${GMP_DIR}/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=${GMP_DIR}/include:$CPATH
```

But after configuring CGAL with the following command

```
cmake -DWITH_CGAL_Core=ON -DWITH_CGAL_Qt5=OFF -DWITH_CGAL_ImageIO=OFF -DWITH_examples=OFF -DWITH_demos=OFF -DGMP_LIBRARIES_DIR:PATH=/data/home/parisa/gmp-6.1.2/lib -DGMP_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/data/home/parisa/gmp-6.1.2/include .
```

I got this error message :

```
 External libraries supported: GMP;GMPXX;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
-- Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
-- Could NOT find GMP (missing:  GMP_LIBRARIES) 
CMake Error at cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:66 (message):
  CGAL requires GMP to be found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:673 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/data/home/parisa/CGAL-4.9.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I tried to change the **lib** in the above command to **libgmp.a**, **libgmp.la** ,and ... but none of them worked!
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Things you could try: `export GMP_DIR=/data/home/parisa/gmp-6.1.2` or `-DGMP_LIBRARIES:PATH=/data/home/parisa/gmp-6.1.2/lib/libgmp.so` (or `.a`).

Comment: Again I got the same error

Comment: I am surprised if you really did, but it is impossible to debug remotely, sorry.

Comment: Thank you. I had the "GMP_DIR=/data/home/parisa/gmp-6.1.2" written in the .bashrc file (the question was editted), and I thought it won't be necessary to explicitly export it before compiling. Now, with exporting it before compiling CGAL the above problem solved.

Comment: You didn't `export GMP_DIR` in .bashrc, so the variable was local to the shell, it was not available to cmake.